# One to one relation on laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8, one-to-one

I have been trying to make a one to one relationship in Laravel and I have not been able to make it work, I still have some doubts. Having two tables eg user (with a fk ) and addresses, should I have two controllers or just one where to execute the CRUD operations of both tables? Since I don't know how to implement it with views to use a single form, none of the examples I've seen on the internet have worked for me, there must be something I'm not considering, thanks!

Controlador de direcciones que funciona correctamente

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\address;
use App\Models\proveedor;
class AddressesController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'pais' =>'required|max:255',
            'estado' =>'required|max:255',
            'direction' =>'required|max:255',
        ]);
        $adrs = new address;
        $adrs->pais = $request->pais;
        $adrs->estado = $request->estado;
        $adrs->direction = $request->direction;
        $adrs->save();
        return redirect()->route('T1')->with('success' , 'Dirección agregada correctamente');
        
   


   }
}
```

Migración de la otra tabla

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateProveedorsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('proveedors', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('id_prov');
            $table->string('rif');
            $table->string('razon_social');
            $table->Biginteger('ad_id')->unsigned()->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('ad_id')->references('id_add')->on('addresses')
                    ->onDelete('cascade')
                    ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('proveedors');
    }
}
```

Comment: The questions and explications must be in English, otherwise I invite you to visit stackoverflow in Spanish. Thanks!

Comment: What you are asking is really a design question or a "best practices".  It really depends on the application and use of the data sets.  Either method is possible. Ask yourself, will you ever have to modify either datasets individually, without modifying the other?  If the answer is yes, then multiple controllers might be the answer.